# "a movie worth seeing" or "a worth seeing movie"

Tags: adjectives, adjective-order, postpositive-adjectives

> 1. It is  *a worth seeing movie* and you must not miss it.
> 2. It is *a movie worth seeing* and you must not miss it.

Which is correct? What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Comment: You can improve this question by telling us which do you think is correct and why.

Answer (score 1):

*Worth* is used as a preposition here, and *worth seeing* is a prepositional or adjectival phrase describing the movie.

While adjectives in English usually come before the nouns they modify, adjectival phrases are (almost?) always placed after the noun, so we'd talk about a "movie worth seeing" rather than a "worth seeing movie*".